# Sc-Fi book with psychic game

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a book from 90's (I think). The French version had a cover in the style of Philippe Caza and the story is about a universe where people can play a sort of "psychic game".

In the game, the players are in another plane of consciousness and become a colour who win by extending themselves. But one day, a new player has a different strategy: he concentrate himself into a single point, becomes solid, then tears apart the others players colour/consciousness (who end up in a coma).

The hero is a male character, a former player that witnessed that new strategy/cheat. He left this game years ago but has to replay (I do not remember why). He found a little (alien?) creature, that accompanied him and seemed to influence the psychic game. So he prepares himself to confront again the other player.

Comment: Was it translated? If so, what was it originally in?